# How to create and return dynamic array with function parameters

Tags: c, pointers

I have a problem returning dynamic array pointer with function parameter. I get segfault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void createArray(int *ptr, int n)
{
    ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        *(ptr + (i - 1)) = i*i;
    }
}

int main() {
    int *array = NULL;
    int n = 5;
    createArray(array, n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have to fill my array with i*i, when I is from 1 to n.
I don't get any errors or warnings. Just message about segmentation fault. *Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)*

Comment: Remember that C only passes function arguments *by value*. That means the value used in the call is *copied* into the functions local argument variable. So modifying the local argument variable itself will only modify this copy, not the original value used in the call. Please do research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: On another note, why `*(ptr + (i - 1))` instead of the easier to read `ptr[i - 1]`?

Comment: Yes, so I should do parameter (int **ptr)?

Comment: Yes that's correct, and call it as `createArray(&array)`

Comment: I did that, but something is still wrong. I also changed *ptr = malloc() part and changed for loop part also *ptr[i - 1] = i * i;

Comment: The problem is `*ptr[i - 1]`, because it's the same as `*(ptr[i - 1])` while you need `(*ptr)[i - 1] `.

Comment: Oooooohhhhh, how did I missed that? Thank you very much

Comment: Alternatively, you could define a `int *createArray(int n)` function and make it return a pointer to the allocated memory. Call it as `array = createArray(n);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change pointer through function parameters like this:

```
void createArray(int **ptr, int n)
{
    *ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        (*ptr)[i - 1] = i*i;
    }
}

int main() {
    int *array = NULL;
    int n = 5;
    createArray(&array, n);
```

Remember to call function like this: **createArray(&array, n);**

Answer (score 1):

Memory must be allocate in the calling function, but not in called.
This variant works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void createArray(int *ptr, int n){
 int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)    {
        *(ptr + (i - 1)) = i*i;
// fprintf(stdout,"%d %d\n", i, *(ptr + (i -1)));fflush(stdout);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, n, *array = NULL;
 void *pvc;
    n = 5;
    array = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    createArray(array, n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)    {
        fprintf(stdout,"%d %d\n", i, array[i]);fflush(stdout);
    }
 pvc = (void *)array;
 free(pvc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It could be allocated in other function too. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I saw example with **ptr, but not tried it.